# Reloading UItableView in Cell button pressing

Tags: uitableview, reloaddata

I want to reload `uitableview` when press a button in `uicellview`. To be clear, what I'm doing is, I created a Favourite button on cellTableView, when I press it first time, it becomes on and the star light on, and when I press it again it becomes off and the star light becomes off, I'm saving the on & off value in sqlite (when it is 1 -> favourited or on, when it is 0 -> not favourited or off). 
My problem is when I press the star button the value is changing in the sqlite but the image of star not change.

This is my code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

[self retrieveDataFromSqlite:1];
}


-(sqlite3 *) openDataBase{

sqlite3 *database;

NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString* dbPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HealthyTips.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"dbPath: %@",dbPath);

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
}else{
    NSLog(@"database opened!");
}

return database;
 }


-(void) retrieveDataFromSqlite:(int)num {

tipsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

sqlite3 *myDatabase = [self openDataBase];

    const char *sqlSelect  = "select * from tips_table";

    if (num == 1) {
       // sqlSelect = "select * from tips_table";
    } else if (num == 2){

    }else{

    }

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, sqlSelect, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            int tips_id = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

            NSString *tips_content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

            NSString *tips_favorite = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

            Tips *tips = [[Tips alloc] initWithUniqueId:tips_id tips_content:tips_content tips_favorite:tips_favorite];

            [tipsArray addObject:tips];


        } // while end

    }// prepare end


    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

sqlite3_close(myDatabase);


 }


-(void) updateFavoriteTip:(NSString *)tipFavorite tipID:(int)tipID {

sqlite3 *myDatabase = [self openDataBase];

sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE tips_table set tip_favorites = '%@' WHERE _id = '%d' ", tipFavorite, tipID] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);


 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [tipsArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tipCell";

TipsTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (!cell) {
    cell = [[TipsTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Tips *temp= (Tips *)[self.tipsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.tipsContent setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.tips_content]];

[cell.tipsContent setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bauhaus Md BT" size:20]];

if ([temp.tips_favorite isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

    [cell.favoriteImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tips_star_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else{

  [cell.favoriteImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tips_star_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

[cell.favoriteImage addTarget:self action:@selector(setFavoriteTip:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.favoriteImage.tag = indexPath.row;

UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
av.opaque = NO;
av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern_gray0.png"];
cell.backgroundView = av;


cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_color.png"]];

return cell;
}

-(IBAction)setFavoriteTip:(UIButton *)sender{

int tag = sender.tag;

Tips *temp= (Tips *)[self.tipsArray objectAtIndex:tag];

NSLog(@"in setFavoriteTip, favorite: %@ - id: %d",temp.tips_favorite, temp.tips_id);

if ([temp.tips_favorite isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

    [self updateFavoriteTip:@"0" tipID:temp.tips_id];

}else{
    [self updateFavoriteTip:@"1" tipID:temp.tips_id];

}

// reloads the table well but the image of star not changing.
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Hope anyone could help me.